# JAVA: Word game query

Tags: java, arrays, integer, game-engine

Hello my fellow programmers!

I have this code so far:

```
public class Levels {
int cLevel;

public void newGame() {
    boolean newGame = true;
    if (newGame) {
        cLevel = 1;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "src/WordGuess/ReadFile/LevelFiles/Level_" + cLevel
                            + ".txt"));
            String cLine;
            while ((cLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(cLine);
            }
            String words[] = new String[list.size()];
            words = list.toArray(words);

            System.out
                    .println("These are your help letters so you can beat that level: "
                            + words[0]);

            for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
                char[] replaceChar = words[i].toCharArray();

                for (int x = 0; x < replaceChar.length; x++) {
                    replaceChar[x] = '*';
                }
                String replacement = new String(replaceChar);

                System.out.println("\f" + replacement);

            }

            System.out.println("\t Score: " + Score(0) + ";\t Lives: "
                    + Lives(5) + ";");

            System.out.println("\n Enter Word:");
            System.in.read();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Oh! Something went terribly wrong. A team of highly trained and koala-fied koalas have been dispatched to fix the problem. If you dont hear from them please restart this program.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private int Lives(int lives) {
    int wrongTries = 0;
    boolean correctWord;
    int counter = 0;

    String livesForm[] = new String[lives];

    // for (int i = 0; i == lives; i++) {
    // livesForm[i] = "♥";
    // }

    return lives;
}

private int Score(int score) {

    return score;
}}
```

So my query is as follows.

I want to show the lives as the heart symbol and still keep the integer value of it for functioning purposes. So as shown in my code example 5 lives to be represented by 5 hearts but still keep the int lives value of 5. As shown also in my example i also tried with an array of strings the size of the integer value 'lives' and to be replaced by hearts. As far as i ran the code no error was displayed whatsoever so i would assume that the array has been populated but i couldn't figure out how to display the array in the console as "Lives: ♥♥♥♥♥".

I have tried with the regular:

```
System.out.println(livesForm[i]);
```

But it did not display anything. I don't know if i have structured my question perfectly clear. I will be glad if any of you fellas can give me an advice or hint. Thank you for spending time on this question!

Comment: I'd like to point out that not everyone on this site is a "fella"...

Comment: @mdewitt I apologize for any inconvenience that my reference as "fellas" to you good people has created a bad impression. I meant it in an absolutely good manner with no bad intention whatsoever. Figured I would "break the ice" in a way.

Comment: It's okay :) just letting you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
public String getLivesAsString(int lives) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(lives);
    for(int i = 0; i < lives; i++) {
        sb.append("♥");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

?

Not sure why you need an array to display an amount of '♥'-symbols defined by an integer?

Comment: Your help is really appreciated! Thank you! I am quite new to JAVA so i did not know about String Builder and the first thought that came to my mind is to create an array. I apologize!

Comment: No need to apologize for being new to the language. Have fun learning it and good luck on your project. :)